# How to solve Xcode SwiftUI "Device Preview Error"?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios-simulator

I was creating a test project for widget. I was using SwiftUI and Xcode version 14.2 (14C18). At the biggining I could automacially see the preview in my iphone if i connect it to my developing mac enviroment and turning the device preview option on from the xcode.

But after some preview in my device i can not see the updated preview in my device any more. At the time of device preview Xcode give an error saying

> HumanReadableSwiftError  | LaunchError: reachedUpdaterLimit

The preview with simulator seems to be working just fine but its not working on device preview.

I restarted the xcode and to change back to previews codes where device preview workd before but still got the error.

[image]